# Erro gravando arquivo binário em Python

Tags: python, arquivo, números-binários

Tenho um programa em Python que recebe um arquivo binário via parâmetro e grava este arquivo. Porém, quando ele grava o arquivo, alguns caracteres ele substitui por uma série de números. Abaixo o arquivo original que recebo como parâmetro:

**ÐT_Ö/¤Ðæ¨®kMµûÀz”Ô(Î,“+œd¼Es¥**

Mas quando o programa grava, olhar para o resultado:

**ÐT_Ö/¤Ðæ¨®kMµûÀz & #148 ; Ô(Î, & #147 ; & #156 ;d¼Es¥**

Vocês podes ver que o caracter **"** entre os caracteres **z** e **Ô** foi substituído pela sequência de **& # 148**;. Também o caracter **+** entre caracteres **Î** e **oe**d foi substituído pela sequência **& # 147**

Abaixo o código do programa Python que fazer o leitiura e gravação de arquivo binário

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
def chamaProg(arquivo): 
   var_file = open("C:\\Nitgen\\arquivo.rec","wb")
   conteudo_texto = var_file.write(arquivo)
   var_file.close(
```

Por que isso está acontecendo?

O que devo fazer para ler e escrever todos os caracteres corretamente?

Por favor, eu preciso resolver com urgência este problema.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arquivos binários tem caracteres [ASCII](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)
o arquivo que você esta tentando gravar tem caracteres [Unicode](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) você tem converter antes.

```
def chamaProg(arquivo): 
  var_file = open("C:\\Nitgen\\arquivo.rec","wb")
  conteudo_texto = var_file.write(arquivo.encode("utf-8"))
  var_file.close()
```

Comment: Não deu certo. Deu erro 500 na hora de chamar o programa

Comment: Se a resposta não deu certo (e está de fato errada) - por que foi aceita?
Em tempo - como a resposta do @drgarcia: você não aborda o erro que de fato acontece aqui: uma gravação de dados binários, recebidos como dados binários não depende do codec de texto.

Answer (score 1):

Tirando um `)` que faltou depois do `close(` (que eu suponho que foi um erro na hora de copiar e colar), o seu código está certo. De onde vem a variável `arquivo`? Como você mencionou erro 500 numa outra resposta, eu imagino que isso é parte de uma aplicativo web? Eu investigaria (mesmo que espalhando `print`s pelo código) de onde vem essa variável; ela está sendo preparada para ser exibida na web, não como string binária.

---

Se você não tem como evitar essa transformação (porque você não controla o código que chama a sua função), você pode tentar a solução “suja” de interpretar a entrada como um fragmento de HTML:

```
import HTMLParser
html_parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
arquivo = html_parser.unescape(arquivo)
```

(mas note que você deve usar isso só pra apagar um incêndio em produção; você tem que descobrir porque `arquivo` está vindo com essas substituições)

Answer (score 0):

Você está tendo problemas com o *encoding* desses caracteres, lhe recomendo abrir o arquivo como **utf8**. Você consegue isso com o pacote built-in **[codecs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html)**. Veja um exemplo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs


def save_file(content):
    with codecs.open('file.rec', 'wb', 'utf8') as f:
        f.write(content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    save_file(u'ÐT_Ö/¤Ðæ¨®kMµûÀz”Ô(Î,“+œd¼Es¥')
```

E mais uma dica, sempre que for trabalhar com arquivos, utilize o *[context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html)* (o *with* desse exemplo), pois ele já fecha o arquivo pra você quando sair do contexto.

Comment: Se a gravação é binária, não deve - e nem faz sentido - ser usado um encoding.